# Determining if ul errors added to HTML to inject class in input

Tags: jquery, html

Here is the resulting code when an error occurs:

```css
.form-group {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.form-control-addition {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" class="form-control form-control-addition" placeholder="Firstname">
   <ul class="errors"><li>Value is required and can't be empty</li></ul>                 
   <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" class="form-control form-control-addition" placeholder="Lastname">
   <ul class="errors"><li>Value is required and can't be empty</li></ul>            
</div>
```

I need a `jQuery` function which detects the presence of  `ul.errors`. If it is present, then an `error` class must be added to the `input` tags above the `ul.errors`.

I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: How is the html generated?

Comment: Oh, and what have you tried? If you really have no idea, I would suggest starting here: http://learn.jquery.com

Comment: @JasonP I updated the html.  This is way too advanced for me.

Comment: `$('.errors').prev().addClass('error');`

Comment: @jkushner Spend at most a couple hours on the site I linked, and this would not be too advanced... as you can see, it's a one-liner.

Comment: @jkushner upvoting the answer could help me to increase my reputations little bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this is script you need to add,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.errors').prev().addClass('error');
});
```

jQuery scripts are always short and tidy. If you need an explanation, here is it.

`$(document).ready(function())` waits for the document (html page) to be read and then it performs the `function()`.

`$('.errors')` selects the Object in DOM with the class .errors, in your case they are `<ul>` tags.
`.prev()` selects the previous Object, in your case its they are `<input>` tags right before `<ul>` tags.
`.addClass('error')` adds the attribute `Class` to the selected Objects.

I think, this is what you have asked for in your question. And usage of  `$(document).ready(function())` entirely depends upon your need. But its a better practice to have your document loaded before performing any `jQuery` functions.